# Next JS advanced feature Content Security policy format

Tags: security, next.js, content-security-policy

I am adding security Policy headers to my application using Security headers advanced feature of next.js
Reference :https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/security-headers
I am quiet clear of how to add the security policies to the next application except the Content Security policy,It does not show any format of the policy in the Documentation :
Taking help of next and developer.mozilla org I have some code in place,that I am attaching herewith. Can anybody help me with the correct format to define content-security policy in Next.JS

Code in Next.config.js

```
const cspPolicy = "default-src 'self';connect-src  'self','preview.contentful.com','*.flippenterprise.net', 'aq.flippenterprise.net','https://www.google-analytics.com','dpm.demdex.net','stats.g.doubleclick.net','lcljoefresh.sc.omtrdc.net','sfml.flippback.com','p.flipp.com','https://sentry.io/',";
const securityHeaders = [
  {
    key: 'Strict-Transport-Security',
    value: 'max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload'
  },
  {
    key: 'X-Frame-Options',
    value: 'SAMEORIGIN'
  },
  {
    key: 'Content-Security-Policy',
    value: cspPolicy
  }
];
const headers = {
  async headers() {
    return [
      {
        // Apply these headers to all routes in your application.
        source: '/(.*)',
        headers: securityHeaders,
      },
    ]
  },
}

const nextConfig = {
  env: {
    search_key: process.env.search_key,
    appDynamicsKey: process.env.appDynamicsKey,
    ENVIRONMENT: process.env.ENVIRONMENT,
  },
  webpack5:false,
  // https://nextjs.org/docs#customizing-webpack-config
  webpack: (webpackConfig) => {
    const { module = {} } = webpackConfig;
    return {
      ...webpackConfig,
      module: {
        ...module,
        rules: [
          ...(module.rules || []),
          {
            test: /\.(txt|png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|gif|jpg|ico|svg)$/,
            use: {
              loader: 'file-loader',
              options: {
                name: '[name]_[hash].[ext]',
                publicPath: '/_next/static/files',
                outputPath: 'static/files',
              },
            },
          },
          {
            test: /\.spec.jsx$/,
            loader: 'ignore-loader',
          },
        ],
      },
    };
  },
};

const sassOptions = {
  sassLoaderOptions: {
    outputStyle: 'compressed',
  },
};

module.exports = withPlugins(
  [[withSass, sassOptions], [withFonts], [withCSS], [withBundleAnalyzer]],
  nextConfig,
  headers,
);
```

Comment: Do not use a comma (`,`) to separate the values in the `connect-src` directive, use a whitespace instead. The domains don't need to be wrapped with quotes either.